# How to properly set environment variables for KDE?

Tags: x11, kde, environment-variables, sddm

I'm using Kubuntu v20.04, which I launch using SDDM. The issue I'm facing is setting some environment variables for my Xsession. I use `~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/env.sh` to export my environment variables, however, I'm observing that a few variables aren't getting set such as `LD_PRELOAD`. I can confirm this because `echo $LD_PRELOAD` returns nothing.

What should be a proper way of doing this?

These are my dotfiles: https://github.com/utkarshverma/dotfiles

Comment: `export`ing variables in `.sh` (executable?) files in `~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/` is the officially [supported way](https://userbase.kde.org/Session_Environment_Variables), it should work (and I can confirm it works on Arch Linux with KDE + SDDM). Where are you executing `echo $LD_PRELOAD`? (E.g. Bash in Konsole?) Did you check if `LD_PRELOAD` is unset/changed somewhere in your shell startup scripts?

Comment: I'm executing `echo $LD_PRELOAD` in my terminal. Also, I'm only using `env.sh` as a startup script so something else is off. And my `env.sh` is getting executed since other variables in it have been exported. I read `~/.xsession_errors` and it does show `$LD_PRELOAD` as being exported, however I can't find anything which might be unsetting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I finally came back to analysing this issue and embarrassingly found out that the exports were working, but I had two conflicting exports, through `.zprofile` and `.xsessionrc` for the same variable.

Also, I've noticed that for some reason, probably security related?, you can't simply inspect the `LD_PRELOAD` variable. It will always return empty.

Though the answer isn't much, I do feel it would be worthwhile to share how I tracked down the issue.

- My first clue was `.xsession-errors` which properly logs all stuff related to X. In that file, I could see that `LD_PRELOAD` was being set twice on logon.
- After that, I just searched the exact line of code in all my files using `grep -rnw ~/* -e "export LD_PRELOAD"`. It clearly indicated the respective files which had the lines, `.zprofile` and `.xsessionrc` and I was able to fix the issue.

> Update:
> It seems that `LD_PRELOAD` was being `unset` by KDE after sourcing `~/.xsessionrc` that's why `export` wasn't reporting anything. I've moved the `export` statement to `~/.zshrc` for now.